# Room persistence Library Database is getting deleted after every restart

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm currently getting into Android development and wanted to use the Room persistence library as my database.

My current code for my DatabaseHelper looks like this:

```
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase{

private static AppDatabase INSTANCE;

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "fitdiary-db";
public abstract UserDAO userDAO();
public abstract ExerciseDAO exerciseDAO();
public abstract ExerciseProgressDAO exerciseProgressDAO();
public abstract WeightDAO weightDAO();

private final MutableLiveData<Boolean> mIsDatabaseCreated = new MutableLiveData<>();

public static AppDatabase getDatabase(Context context){

    if(INSTANCE == null){
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build();

    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
public void destroyInstance(){
    INSTANCE = null;
}

private void updateDatabaseCreated(final Context context) {
    if (context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).exists()) {
        setDatabaseCreated();
    }
}

private void setDatabaseCreated(){
    mIsDatabaseCreated.postValue(true);
}


public LiveData<Boolean> getDatabaseCreated() {
    return mIsDatabaseCreated;
}
```

so if I start my app why does it always create a new database?

Comment: are you handling migration if not then remove fallbackToDestructiveMigration, which is not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**fallbackToDestructiveMigration**

Allows Room to destructively recreate database tables if Migrations that would migrate old database schemas to the latest schema version are not found.

if migration not found then It recreates the database and clear all data.

See here for more details https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#fallbackToDestructiveMigration()

try removing fallbackToDestructiveMigration

```
public static AppDatabase getDatabase(Context context){

    if(INSTANCE == null){
        INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();

    }
    return INSTANCE;
}
```